# Spark Shell - system cannot find the path specified in Windows 10

Tags: apache-spark, spark-shell

I am trying to run Spark on Windows 10. I have placed spark files and winutils in the folder. I have specified the path in User and System Variable as well. But when running the spark-shell command it gives me an error.

Error Message - The system cannot find the path specified.

```
  SPARK_HOME - C:\BigData\Spark
  HADOOP_HOME - C:\BigData\Hadoop
  JAVA_HOME - C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_281

  USER PATH - %SPARK_HOME%\bin, %HADOOP_HOME%\bin, %JAVA_HOME%\bin
```

Please help me in resolving the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Java path was having space in it.

Previous Path - C:/Program Files/Java
Updated Path - C:/Java